# Compute limit of sequence

Tags: limits

Let $(x_n)$ be real sequences such that $x_{1}=\dfrac{1}{3}, x_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{3}x_{2n-1}, x_{2n+1}=\dfrac{1}{3}+x_{2n}, n=1,2,\cdots $.

Compute $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sup x_{n} \text{ and } \lim_{x \to \infty} \inf x_{n}. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Notice that if $n$ is even,
$$x_{n+2} = x_n/3 + 1/9$$
and if $n$ is odd
$$x_{n+2} = x_n/3+1/3$$
with initial conditions $x_1 = 1/3, x_2 = 1/9$.

Analyze each of the two subsequences which are easy to do.

Comment: I proved :$\lim x_{2n}=\frac12$ and $\lim x_{2n+1}=\frac32$.But how to find $\sup x_n$ and $\inf x_n$ as $n\to +\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$
x_{2n}=x_{2n-1}/3=(1/3+x_{2n-2})/3=x_{2n-2}/3+1/9
$$

$$
x{2n+1}=1/3+x_{2n}=1/3+x_{2n-1}/3
$$

and we have $x_1=1/3$, we can add $x_0=0$, which is ok by the definition

then sovle the recursive sequence, we get

$$
x_{2n} = \frac{1}{6}(1-\frac{1}{3^n})
$$

$$
x_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{3^n}
$$

so

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup x_{n} = 1/2
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf x_{n} = 1/6
$$